# How to import new character as first person view in Unity version 5.3.4p3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and my Unity version is 5.3.4p3 . I'm following some tutorials from [Jimmy Vegas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eOIyQc1cBL4&index=2&list=PLZ1b66Z1KFKik2g8D4wrmYj4yein4rCk8&spfreload=10) beginners playlist Unity version 5 and he says:

"if you want to import new character follow this direction...

```
Assets -> Import Package -> Characters
```

"

But all I have is this:

```
Assets -> Import Package -> Custom...
```

So how to import new character as first person view in Unity version 5.3.4p3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you might be missing the Standard Assets from the Asset Store.

When installing Unity you have the option to install some packages that come with Unity, and some people skip over them.

Download the Standard Assets here: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/32351

Comment: And default location for standard assets is in your unity install folder for example, "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Standard Assets\" (so if that folder is empty, you wont have anything listed on that import package menu).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Unity wont give you an error message so when you drag and drop, Check your console as I may tell you certain information about the issue
Also, when you first start I recommend importing ALL of the default packages as they already have a pretty good premade first person charector